# how to check if string start with {SOME_STRING}

Tags: android, string, matcher

I would like to return true if string starts with "{SOME_STRING}". examples of true returned:

```
{A}
{AB}
{}
{ABC}
```

otherwise, return false.

I tried:

```
return str.matches("{%s}")
```

but it doesn't work
I tried:

```
return str.matches("{//s}")
return str.matches("^{.*}")
```

nothing worked.

Comment: What is `SOME_STRING` here? how is this not possible with `startsWith()` method of String ?

Comment: some string can be any letter\letters. it can be "mda", "bb", ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
public void matchingContext(String myWord)
    {
        String input="{SOME STRING} some other string";
        String regex = "^("+myWord+").*";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
    }
```

and when you want to call the method with {SOME STRING}, you have to escape the characters `{` and `}` first, so this would look like `matchingContext("\\{SOME STRING\\}")`

Answer (score 0):

use `str.startsWith("A")`